# Pass request instance to Model Observer, Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've just learned of model observers and would like to move some of my logic from controller to observer.  Here's what I have:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    WorkOrder::observe(WorkOrderObserver::class);
}
```

WorkOrderObserver.php

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Site;
use App\WorkOrder;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\WorkOrderNumber;

class WorkOrderObserver
{

    public function creating(WorkOrder $workOrder)
    {
        $branchOfficeId = Site::findOrFail($request->site_id)->branch_office_id;
        $today = Carbon::today('America/Los_Angeles');
        $todaysWorkOrderCount = WorkOrder::where('created_at_pst', '>=', $today)->count();

        $workOrder->work_order_number = (new WorkOrderNumber)
            ->createWorkOrderNumber($branchOfficeId, $todaysWorkOrderCount);
        $workOrder->completed_by = null;
        $workOrder->status_id = 1;
        $workOrder->work_order_billing_status_id = 1;
        $workOrder->created_at_pst = Carbon::now()->timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
            ->toDateTimeString();
    }

}
```

Problem is accessing the request from within the observer.  I don't see anything in the docs.  I found one thread here that refers to this and it suggested using the request helper function.  I tried `request('site_id')` but it was empty.

Comment: Did you try taking \Illuminate\Http\Request $Request in argument? I think it will be automatically injected.

Comment: I did try that, but got an error... `TypeError: Argument 2 passed to App\Observers\WorkOrderObserver::creating() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given`

Answer (score 16):

This is so simple I'm a bit embarrassed I posted it. Anyway, in case someone finds this thread, here's the solution. In your observer, add a constructor that accepts the request and sets a property.

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Comment: Was able to get the request using this answer too.

Answer (score 2):

You can request object using app helper function of Laravel.

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(WorkOrderNumber $workorder)
{
    $this->request = app('request');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get request data in observer laravel

request() helper should work:

```
if (request()->has('password')) {
    $user->password = bcrypt(request()->password);
}
```

ref: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/get+request+data+in+observer+laravel